# scan directories of .pdf and .ps files for keyword in title and author

Tags: pdf, postscript

I have got directories full of research papers. I would like to scan the files for keywords in the titles, the author lists, etc.

Does a tool for that purpose exist?

Comment: Do you mean info in metadata (PDF "Author"/"Subject"/"Title" tags, PS "Creator"/"Title") or in the content?

Comment: Searching for patterns can be made using REGEX and `grep`. You may want to have a look at the `pdftotext` utility as well.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Whatever is used in downloadable articles (on arxiv or by publishers)